# to draw control flow graph of a c program from generated contents of bison parser

Tags: bison

i have to design a parser to show control flow of  a c program using flow chart
I generated a c parser and lexer by using bison.

but I don't know how could I generate Context Flow Graph using the generated parser and lexer.
and how i will save the parsed contents...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like course work to me.

DOT (http://www.graphviz.org/) is a good graphing package, which parses a text file and produces graphs from it. Its then a matter of building up an intermediate representation in memory using your parser, finding main, and following the control statements, outputting who is called from whom in a form DOT can recognize.